# Как изменить параметры IntentFilter( "android.intent.action.TIME_TICK)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня возникла необходимость использовать для вызова уведомлений broadcast, и  у меня возникла проблема: я хочу, чтобы уведомления приходили каждый час, но с TICK они поступают каждую минуту. Есть ли альтернативный объект, или как можно изменить его параметры? Заранее спасибо, желательно продемонстрировать эти "махинации".

**Метод вызова уведомлений**:

```
public void showNotifications() {

    this.registerReceiver(mTimeBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.TIME_HOUR"));
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Base.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
        .setTicker("Новое уведомление")
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle("Прошёл час")
        .setContentText("Пора ставить оценку");

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    NM.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

**broadcast**:

```
public class TimeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 104;
    private AlarmManager manager;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        manager= (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent fakeIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(context,Notify.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time,
                60000, fakeIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: `TIME_TICK` - это о другом, для работы с `AlarmManager` он не нужен. Поскольку Вы создаёте явный интент (с указанием класса), `action` вообще можно не указывать.

Comment: Оставил, так как если убрать, то уведомления не вызываются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить еще одни 0, если не ошибаюсь 1000 = 1 секунде

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 600000, fakeIntent);
```

Comment: Мысль в верном направлении, но час будет равен `60 * 60 * 1000` - обычно для наглядности так и пишут выражением.

Comment: Алгоритм не выполняется без TIME_TICK, поэтому изначально я задал вопрос именно по изменению параметров intentFilter

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению ответ я так и не нашёл, поэтому пришлось танцевать с бубном и химичить с классом Broadcast а также изменить вызов этого класса в методе showNotifications

**Измененный метод вызова**

```
public void showNotifications() {

    String head =" ";
    this.mTimeBroadCastReceiver.onReceive(this,new Intent(this,TimeBroadcastReceiver.class));
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Base.class);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setTicker("Новое уведомление")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Прошёл час")
            .setContentText("Пора ставить оценку");



    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    NM.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

**Broadcast**

```
public class TimeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 104;
private AlarmManager manager;
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    manager= (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent fakeIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(context,Notify.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3600);
    long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time, 1000*60*60, fakeIntent);
}
```

}